# Artifactory Docker Registry Free /var partition space

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, jfrog-container-registry

Due to irregularization of docker images being pushed to jfrog docker registry, my /var partition is currently FULL.

As i am able to ssh into the machine, i wanted to know can i directly go about deleting the images at the /var location as I am not able to start artifactory service due to insufficient space.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker images are stored as checksum binary files in the filestore. You will have no way of knowing what checksum belongs to what image and since images often share the same layer, even deleting a single one can corrupt several images.

For the short term, I recommend moving (not deleting) a few binary files to allow you to start your registry back up. You can also delete the backup directory (since backup is on by default and you may not actually want/need it and it occupies a lot of space). Once that is done, start it up and delete enough images to clear enough space OR, preferably, expand the filestore size OR, better yet, move it to a different partition so you don't mix the app/OS with the application data. In any case, when you have more free space, move the binary files back to their original location.